# Apparent inconsistency in the type declaration of `JSONSerialization.data`

Tags: swift, types, swift3

Here is the type signature of `JSONSerialization.data`:

```
class func data(withJSONObject obj: Any, options opt: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions = []) throws -> Data
```

The weird thing is that `JSONSerialization.WritingOptions` is a struct, while the default value [] is an array, not a match. Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

[`JSONSerialization.WritingOptions`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/jsonserialization.writingoptions) conforms to the [`OptionSet`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/optionset) protocol, which inherits from [`SetAlgebra`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/setalgebra), and that inherits from [`ExpressibleByArrayLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/expressiblebyarrayliteral).

Therefore you can create a `JSONSerialization.WritingOptions` value from a (possibly empty) array *literal* (using the
[`init(arrayLiteral elements: Self.Element...)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/expressiblebyarrayliteral/2299069-init) initializer):

```
JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: obj, options: [])
JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: obj, options: [.prettyPrinted])
```

The same is true for the reading options (which have more than
one possible value), for example:

```
JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: json, options: [.allowFragments, .mutableLeaves])
```

and many other `OptionSet` types.

In addition,  `OptionSet` inherits from [`RawRepresentable`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/rawrepresentable)
with an *integer* `RawValue`. Each possible value is represented
as an integer with zero, one, or multiple bits set to one.

But note that `[]` or `[.prettyPrinted]` in above examples are 
array *literals* (from which a `JSONSerialization.WritingOptions` value is created), and not arrays. This would not compile:

```
let noOptions = Array<JSONSerialization.WritingOptions>()
let json = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: obj, options: noOptions)
// cannot convert value of type 'Array<JSONSerialization.WritingOptions>' to expected argument type 'JSONSerialization.WritingOptions'
```

Comment: Still doesn't seem right. `.prettyPrinted` is of type `JSONSerialization.WritingOptions` already, how could `[.prettyPrinted]` conform to the same type?

Comment: @qed: `OptionSetType` defines `associatedtype Element = Self` which means (if I understand it correctly), that the same type is used for both the set and a single element of the set. – Also `[.prettyPrinted]` is an array *literal*, not an array.

Comment: Ok, so `.allowFragments`, `.mutableLeaves` and `[.allowFragments, .mutableLeaves]` are all of the same type? What's the rationale behind this strangeness? I was thinking why AppCode could not autocomplete this kind of parameters properly, now I see...

Comment: @qed: Yes they are. And they are all stored as an integer `rawValue` with one or more bits set to one.

Comment: Ah, ok. I see, for space efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4** : This works !

```
JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: [])
```